# NestJS cannot pass params from middleware to controller action

Tags: express, nestjs

trying to pass from auth middleware "userInfo" into Controller action,
but when using @Param decorator to read request.params object from Controller action,
it always empty object

Here are code example
https://codesandbox.io/s/nest-forked-049en?file=/src/app.module.ts

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) not as a photo

Comment: just added code example

Comment: Do not post images, instead include the code snippets in your question please. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: looks like bug in NestJS

Comment: Why are you assigning to `req.params`? Wouldn't that overwrite any URL parameters you may send in? Why not use some custom `req` field like `req.userinfo`? Or do like passport does and use `req.user`?

Comment: req object immutable